# Location of database in Phone Gap for Android

Tags: cordova

I run all examples of storage class of Phone gap and developed the code as mentioned in

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage.

Then at which location the DB file will be created?

Answer (score 1):

The location of the database file is different in android 4.4. 
My app on android 4.1 has the db at "file:///data/data/{package_name}/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db"
but on Android 4.4 the db file's at "file:///data/data/{package_name}/app_webview/databases/file__0/1".

I wrote a simple [plugin](https://github.com/jamirooo/DatabasePath-cordova) for cordova that makes this distinction and returns a string with the full path of the db file. However it's not developed for other platforms like iOS or Windows Phone. Feel free to collaborate.

Comment: hi bruno..I am trying the same on Android 4.4 but I am facing the same issue as mentioned over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991630/android-version-4-4-sqlite-error-in-phonegap

Comment: I didn't use a prepoulated database as pointed out in the link you referenced, but as you can see in my response, the default database location changes on android 4.4. I think that if you want to use a prepopulated database on android 4.4 you have to copy your database file to "file:///data/data/{package_name}/app_webview/databases/file__0/" and name it just "1".

Comment: I tried loading a prepopulated database ..but it seems that the folder structure keeps on changing..see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991630/android-version-4-4-sqlite-error-in-phonegap#comment39485176_21991630  .......do you know any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

on which platform?

on Android the DB file is located in /data/data/{app.package}/databases and /data/data/{app.package}/app_database
(credits: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/_OMN5C5flq8)

Comment: I am not able to find path of data.Please also answer of this too

Comment: again: on what platform?
If you are using android and Eclipse, open DDMS perspective (Window --> Open perspective --> DDMS) while the emulator is running, click on "file explorer" and navigate to the path I wrote to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PhoneGap for Android you will find the database you created in the following folder

> /data/data/{{full_package_name}}/app_database

Your app database is typically created under a folder like this:

> file__0/0000000000000001.db (Please note that the number could change in your specific case, but you get the idea)

If you want to browse the data on that database, you could do

```
sqlite3 {{db_file_name.db}}
.header on
.tables
select * from {{tablename}}
.schema {{tablename}}
```

Comment: the /data folder on my nexus 7 (android 4.4) is empty. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The DB file will be stored at /data/data/{package_name}/databases.

I recommend use "SQLitePlugin":

[Cordova-SQLitePlugin](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)