# Phonegap Database Location

Tags: cordova

I have developed a phonegap application using cordova-2.4.0 for android.
I have used the following code to create a database.

```
      var db = window.openDatabase(g_dbName, "1.0", "MyDB", 1000000);
```

I want to retrieve the location in my android device where the database file is created.

Answer (score 0):

Android :

```
   in Ecllipse: Goto DDMS -> FileExplorar -> data ->  data -> packagename -> file_0 -> yourdb.db
```

IOS  :

```
   /Users/userid/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/unique id of package(221FEC9E-0A3C-48D8-95A2-B418CB0F1AE1)/Library/WebKit/LocalStorage/file__0
```

Comment: I need to know the database location in android device's file system.
Please help!

Comment: can't view form device you must need android emulator

Answer (score 0):

Check [my answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791166/location-of-database-in-phone-gap-for-android/24769730#24769730). I wrote a [plugin](https://github.com/jamirooo/DatabasePath-cordova) for cordova that gets the database full path on the android device, however it currently does not work in other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

•   To view the database you need an Android Emulator, follow these steps:

> Open Eclipse. Click on Windows > Open Perspective > DDMS. Go to File Explorer.

[image]

> Then go to /data/data/package_name/databases (My package name was com.example.Sample).

[image]

> You can see the database.

[image]