# android version 4.4+ sqlite error in Phonegap

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova

I am using prepopulated Database and copied DB using 
[this link](http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html) this code works smooth for android below 4.4 versions.

But, as i made a test demo for android 4.4+ versions it creates new folder as "app_webview" and creates new database for it.
4.4+ default structure - 
/data/data/{packageName}/app_webview/databases/Databases.db
/data/data/{packageName}/app_webview/databases/file__0/1

and when i copied my database.db and my_db.sqlite file to "app_webview" using above link the 
db = window.openDatabase("my_db", "1.0", "My_db 1.0", 200000);

overrides my all files and generates its default structure. 
(Please check my below images how it overrides to its default structure)

[image: my DB structure]

Structure get changed when call reaches to - 
db = window.openDatabase("my_db", "1.0", "My_db 1.0", 200000);

[image: Overided Data]

note - I am not using SqlitePlugin.

Comment: hi umesh..can you tell me how did you resolve the issue

Comment: Hi Parth Doshi for 4.4+ it automatically generates file name as "1"

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this Project](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to copy a predefined database without any problems.

Comment: My issue is for android 4.4+ versions when i copy my prepopulated database and after calling - 
window.openDatabase("my_db", "1.0", "My_db 1.0", 200000);
my database file gets replaced by Phonegaps default DB.(FolderStructure replaced) 
why is this happening for 4.4+ versions in android?

Comment: hi umesh..can you tell me how did you resolve the issue