# unable to copy database in Android kitkat 4.4 using phonegap

Tags: android, database, cordova

I am facing the exact issue as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991630/android-version-4-4-sqlite-error-in-phonegap). In all previous Android versions before 4.4, my database gets copied to the right folder.

However in Android Kitkat, the same code doesn't work as the structure of the folder changes. why is this happening? Is this a bug with Android kitkat?